# Troubles when retrieving data with Mongoose and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I got some problem when I try to retrieve some data of my DB in an array. We are trying to retrieve an array of "bo" through this request :

```
boardModel.find(null, 'bonus',function(err, allBo){
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() *allBo.length));
result = allBo[rand];
console.log(result);
```

But when we do that, it return the whole things in the first cell.

Here's one part of our MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "53722eaae02f6ed00fbf4e7a"
    },
    "thème": [
        {
            "id_th": 1
        },
        {
            "nb_tronçons": 5
        },
        {
            "tronçon": "Commercialisation"
        }
    ],
    "malus": [
        "-2"
    ],
    "bonus": [
        {
            "bo": "+2",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "53722eaae02f6ed00fbf4e7c"
            }
        },
        {
            "bo": "+3",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "53722eaae02f6ed00fbf4e7b"
            }
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
```

Edit : So, only the allBo[0] contains something and it contains this part :

```
"bonus": [
        {
            "bo": "+2",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "53722eaae02f6ed00fbf4e7c"
            }
        },
        {
            "bo": "+3",
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "53722eaae02f6ed00fbf4e7b"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What is the top level collection called? Have you console.logged the allBo value to see what is being returned?

Comment: The top level collection is called "boards" and the log of allBo return the "bonus" part of the document but in one cell of the array.

Comment: What do you mean by in one cell of the array, can you add the content of the allBo to your question?